# 'service any-service-name start' command does not work in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, init-script

I tried to start/stop/restart with the `service` command but it does not work. I have to use `/etc/init.d/any-service` to start/stop/restart the service.

I have checked the logs but I can't see any clue to solve this. Even I tried with `apt-get check` to find any mismatch on configuration...

the `/usr/sbin/service` is present but doesn't show any message. For example, if I do `service tomcat7 stop` , the messages where Tomcat is stoping didn't show. And if I do a `ps -fea |grep tomcat`, Tomcat is still running...

Comment: You might want to try `systemctl` instead. e.g. `systemctl stop tomcat7`, `systemctl status tomcat7`